# enabling index.php on linux mint apache2

Tags: php5, apache-2.2

I've got a copy of linux mint 10 (julia). I've got apache2 and php packages installed.

the php5 files are in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.

Browse to a directory with an 'index.php', and the php file is served up, not executed.

The access log has

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2011:13:09:40 -0400] "GET /typo3/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33147 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Linux Mint/10 (Julia) Firefox/3.6.15"
```

and the error log has nuthin.

php5.conf contains the following, which would seem to exclude .php, but adding it to the match didn't help.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same file on an Ubuntu system I have to hand is

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

you might try and see if that works.

Comment: Bingo! What were the mint people thinking?